Apache EChart SplitNumber is not working as intended
I believe this might be due to a misunderstanding on my end regarding echart's xAxis and yAxis splitNumber variable.
If you look at my example here, with the xAxis, with splitNumber at 10, I have 15 splitlines, however with splitNumber at 5 (changing the splitNumber from 10 to 5), I have more than 5 splitlines. If possible may I know what's the logic behind this splitNumber, and how can I use it to indicate the number of splits that I want to see? Thank you.
May I know why is  that the case. Below is a picture with xAis.splitNumber set to 10.


splitNumber does not work very well with axis type 'time'. From the documentation you linked:

Note that this number serves only as a recommendation, and the true segments may be adjusted based on readability

So if you want to force a specific number of splits i would recommend to compute an interval based on your minimal and maximal values and set minInterval and maxInterval.
Example:
const margin = 0.1;
const interval = (maxValue - minValue) / splitNumber;
const minInterval = interval * (1 - margin);
const maxInterval = interval * (1 + margin);

